# 2 band inductor value?

Tags: inductor

An old circuit board I have (that is very old) has these inductors on it.  I can't find any mention online of a 2-band color code.  What value would these inductors be?

I thought maybe one of the colours had faded but even on close inspection I can't see any indication there used to be another band anywhere.

[image: inductors]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnApz.jpg)

Comment: They look more like 0 ohm resistors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are `0 Ohm` resistors, basically a trace/connection between 2 parts on the PCB. This can be used if you want to seperate 2 parts of the PCB with only a small pathway to control the flow of the current. Or to disable/enable certain parts of the PCB if it's multifunctional and not everything is needed.